# batch convert base64 encoded file names Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, base64, decode, batch-processing

In windows, how can I batch convert base64 file names in a folder to their original names assuming every file name in the folder is encoded with base64

Comment: Please show us what you have tried yourself already and possibly some examples to go with that.

Comment: I have only tried inputting the file name into this site and it gave a legitimate name after pressing decode https://www.base64decode.org/. So I am wondering how I can do this to all files in a folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by iterating the path of the files and try to decode the base64 basenames of those files. If that succeeds, rename the file.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'TheFolderWhereTheFilesAre>' -File | ForEach-Object {
    # store the file name for when we hit the catch block
    $file = $_.FullName  
    try {
        $newBase = [System.Text.Encoding]::Default.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($_.BaseName))
        $_ | Rename-Item -NewName ('{0}{1}' -f $newBase, $_.Extension) -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning "Error renaming file '$file':`r`n$_.Exception.Message"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the code for a batch file? Or another language? Sorry I know very little about programming

Comment: @itchynutsack69 this is PowerShell. You did tag your question as such..

Comment: Yes I tagged with powershell only because I used someone elses command to rename files before using powershell. By the way this works like a charm thanks :)